# mqtt - Is it a good idea to one-time subscribe to a topic, wait for a message and then immediately unsubscribe?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mqtt, publish-subscribe

### EDIT:

I found out about the retain message flag on mqtt servers. This might be what I'm looking for. Instead of querying for the current state directly, I can subscribe to a topic and the broker will send the last published state directly.

I'll update this answer after I tried the retain message flag.

---

Let's say I have a switch that is connected to a mqtt broker. That switch knows whether it's switched ON or OFF.
When I publish to the topic "switch/status", the switch recognises that and in turn publishes a message to "switch" with the content "isTurnedOn: (true|false)".

My question is, is the following workflow bad practice or is there a better way to do this?

1. A client subscribes to topic "switch"
2. Same client publishes a message to "switch/status"
3. The client waits until it receives a response on topic "switch" *or* timeout after *n* seconds. Process the result.
4. Client unsubscribes from that topic.

One switch might not make much of an impact, but what if there were say 10 switches. That would mean 10 separate subscription requests, 10 responses/possible timeouts and then 10 separate un-subscription request.

Comment: What benefits do you think there are to subscribing/unsubscribing?

Comment: @hardillb I don't think I understand your question. Could you explain or rephrase it differently?

Comment: Why do you think what you have described is a good idea

Comment: @hardillb I don't particularly think the way I described is a good idea. That's why I asked the question in the first place. It's more a implementation requirement. I thought about how I could realise a kind of direct communication between two devices while maintaining the de-coupling that a MQTT broker provides and that's the first idea I had. If you know a better way, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: When I say "direct communication" I mean one device can ask another device it's current state. E.g.: 
Web Interface: "Hey Lamp, what is your current state?"
Lamp: "Hello, Web Interface! I am currently turned on"